# How do I redefine a function within a function?

Tags: c++, tree

Maybe there's an easier way to do this, but what I'm doing is writing a class that consists of two Binary Search Trees. I'm using those trees to store structs that contain Olympic medal counts for various countries. Here's the struct:

```
struct Country{
    string country;
    int rank;
    int gold;
    int silver;
    int bronze;

    Country(): country(""), rank(NULL), gold(NULL), silver(NULL), bronze(NULL){}
    Country(string ncountry, int ngold, int nsilver, int nbronze): country(ncountry), rank(NULL), gold(ngold), silver(nsilver), bronze(nbronze) {}
}
```

I then want to add a new Country to each of the trees. The problem I'm running into is that I need to overload the comparison operators (>, <, ==, !=, <=, >=) in order for the Binary Search Tree methods to work. That's not particularly difficult, but they need to be differently defined. While I'm adding to the country tree, I need to be comparing country names, and while I'm adding to the rank tree I need to be comparing ranks. So I'm looking to do something like this:

```
void addNewCountry(string name, int goldMedalCount, int silverMedalCount, int bronzeMedalCount){
    //Define comparison operators to compare based on rank
    rankTree.add(CountryNode(name, goldMedalCount, silverMedalCount, bronzeMedalCount));
    //Define comparison operators to compare based on country
    countryTree.add(CountryNode(name, goldMedalCount, silverMedalCount, bronzeMedalCount));
}
```

Normally I'd have multiple methods, but I can't really do that in the case of operator overloading best I can tell. Thanks.

Comment: Scratch what I originally said, make a template parameter for the tree be a comparison object, or something similar. It makes more sense that passing comparison objects to `add` functions, especially if every call would use the same type.

Comment: @JamesRoot Thanks for the advice! I ended up using a different method, but I learned a lot about templates while looking into the one you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was executing a pointer to a function within the operator overload. This way I can reassign the pointer to another function when I need to, thereby changing the internals of the function without redefining it via the usual channels. Here's a short demo program of what I did:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int (*pointerSwitch) (int) = NULL;

int square(int input){
    return input*input;
}

int doubleNum(int input){
    return input*2;
}

int variableFunction(int input){
    return pointerSwitch(input);
}

int main(){
    pointerSwitch = &square;
    cout << variableFunction(10) << endl;
    pointerSwitch = &doubleNum;
    cout << variableFunction(10) << endl;
}
```

We run the same function twice but modify the internals. The output is:

```
100
20
```